# How do I create projects on Xcode 7 using wxWidgets?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, wxwidgets

My specifications are up to date (OS X El Capitan, 10.11). Here are details on what I've tried so far.

I've followed the (Terminal) installation steps included in the wxWidgets download:

```
mkdir build-cocoa-debug
cd build-cocoa-debug
../configure --enable-debug
make
cd samples; make;cd ..
cd demos;   make;cd ..
```

Then, I followed the [wxWidgets wiki guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications) for creating Xcode projects.

Of course, there were plenty of compilation errors. After taking care of an incorrectly typed include, there were still issues. For the most part, they were undeclared identifiers and incomplete types, but my attention went to one in particular:

```
"No Target! You should use wx-config program for compilation flags!"
```

After researching, I believe I need to use wx-config to find what flags to input into the "Other Linker Flags" option in Xcode. However, I can't seem to utilize wx-config in Terminal.

I'm not sure if I'm dealing with the core issue. If I am, how do I use wx-config? And if I'm not, please steer me in the right direction.

Thank you.

## ***** EDIT: *****

I've used wx-config to find which flags I needed to input into "Other Linker Flags" and "Preprocessor Macros" in Xcode. This significantly reduced the amount of errors and warnings that I was facing.

Unfortunately, these new errors are esoteric to me:

[Error/Warning Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsmvH.png)

How do I remove these errors so I can run this project?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *"can't seem to use wx-config"*. What happens when you try?

Comment: @Mark When I try, say, "wx-config -cxxflags", I get a "wx-config: command not found" log.

Comment: Ok, you have probably have not set your PATH correctly so that `bash` can find `wx-config`. First, you need to find `wx-config` so try `find / -name wx-config` in the Terminal and it will tell you where you have installed it. Then you will know the full path to it - come back when you find it.

Comment: @Mark Awesome, I am now in the correct directory.

Comment: So if it is in `/usr/freddy`, you can either run `/usr/freddy/wx-config`, or you can edit your `$HOME/.profile` and set your PATH to `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/freddy` them `bash` will know where it is every time you log in.

Comment: @Mark That helped a lot. Using wx-config, I was able to see which flags to add to "Preprocessor Macros" and "Other Linker Flags", reducing my log to 5 errors and 4 warnings.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. If you get stuck again, remember questions are free so just ask away!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm finally able to compile and run wxWidgets programs using Xcode 7. I've found and followed [this awesome guide](http://web.eng.fiu.edu/watsonh/eel3160/WxMac.pdf) (of which step 3 seems to now be irrelevant).

In case the link breaks, here is a summary of the steps that helped me:

* * * * * *

Open Terminal and install Homebrew by inputting:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Then, input:

```
brew install wxmac
```

Open Xcode and create a Command Line Tool C++ project.

Back in Terminal, input:

```
wx-config --libs
```

Once inputted, copy everything outputted by the Terminal and place it into Other Linker Flags (found in Build Settings of your Xcode project).

At Terminal, input:

```
wx-config -–cxxflags
```

Again, copy everything outputted except this time place it into Other C++ Flags (do not erase what is currently in that section).

Then, of course don't forget to include wx/wx.h and don't forget to have at least an empty main function if you want it to run.

* * * * * *

I'm not at a place where I can create Cocoa projects/products, but that's totally fine. I simply wanted a canvas to familiarize  myself with the wxWidgets library.

I hope this post will be helpful to others.

Comment: Hey man, great posting, both the question and the answer. They were helpful to me. Also, great profile description!

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! It's --cxxflags and not -cxxflags btw. Cheers.

Comment: This also works if you built the code manually via configure & make.  Just use the terminal to cd into the build directory and wx-config should be right there.

Answer (score -1):

Arman,
First couple of questions:

1. What OS are you trying to compile?
2. What is your requirements for the minimal OSX version?
3. I presume you are trying to compile the latest Git HEAD. Please correct me if its not the case.

Now, couple of recommendations:

1. Try to run "../configure --help" and see at all the different options you can set.
2. Try to run "../configure --enable-debug --with-mac-osx-version-min=10.x --with-cocoa". This command has to be run after removing the build directory completely and pretending you are starting over.
3. Try to open the "minimal.xcode" project in the samples/minimnal directory, add the minimal.cpp file to it and compile. If it compiles and runs fine, then you made a mistake setting up the project of your own.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I ran "../configure --enable-debug --with-mac-osx-version-min=10.x --with-cocoa" and ended up with two similar errors:  "cannot initialize a variable of type 'WebBackForwardList \*' with an rvalue of type 'WKBackForwardList \*" and the log: "make: \*\*\* [webviewdll_osx_webview_webkit.o] Error 1"